# Does FirstOrDefault return a reference to the item in the collection or the value?

Tags: c#, linq

Does FirstOrDefault return a reference to the item in the collection or the value of the item?

```
var obj = myCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Param == "match condition");  
if (obj != null)
{
    obj  = newObjectOfCollectionType; //if found, replace with the changed record
}
```

Will this code replace the object reference in the myCollection with the new object, or will it do nothing to myCollection?

Comment: You can make changes to the object it returns, but you cannot replace it.  So if you did something like `obj.SomeProperty = newPropertyValue` it will update the object in your collection.

Comment: Sequences are read only so you can't change it. You need to create a new collection. myCollection = mycollection.Select(x => x.Param == "match condition" ? newObjectOfCollectionType : x).ToList() // or ToArray/ToDictionary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it will do nothing; obj is a reference to the object (if the collection is of a reference type), and not the object itself.
If the collection is of a primitive type, then obj will be a *copy* of the value in the collection, and, again- this means that the collection will not change.

Edit:
to replace the object, it depends what your collection's type is.
If it's `IEnumerable<T>`, then it's not mutable, and you won't be able to change it.
The best option you have is to create a new collection and modify that, like so-

```
T [] array = myCollection.ToArray();
array[index] = newObject;
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a good way to replace the object if it exits in the collection?

Comment: @sJhonny: That still won't change `myCollection`. It will just change `array`.

Comment: that's right; like i said- "The best option you have is to create a new collection..."

Comment: you don't need to create a new collection (see my answer below)

Answer (score 15):

```
var obj = myCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Param == "match condition");  
if (obj != null)
{
    obj  = newObjectOfCollectionType; --> this will not reflect in the collection
}

var obj = myCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Param == "match condition");  
if (obj != null)
{
    obj.Property = newValue; --> this will reflect in your object in the original collection
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It does nothing to the collection. You can change the collection like this:

```
int index = myCollection.FindIndex(x => x.Param == "match condition");  
if (index != -1)
{
    myCollection[index]  = newObjectOfCollectionType;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the EXACT question of the poster, but I believe it solves the problem they were having. It solved mine! I didn't know about "FindIndex" until seeing this post. Thanks to a SO user with 1 reputation for helping me! LINQ is a very robust!

Comment: This solved my issue I don't believe that Vishal's answer is correct or at least it didn't work reliably for me. obj.Property = newValue was sometimes not reflected in the original collection, however myCollection[index] .property = newValue seems to work reliably.

Answer (score 2):

It returns the value that's in the collection. But that value, in your case, is a reference.

It does not return the position. Your code will not change the collection.

Comment: "in your case, is a reference" - why? The type of items can be a `struct` with `Param` property.

Comment: @Dennis: The code has `if (obj != null)`. If `obj` were a value type (`struct`), that line of code would not compile.

Answer (score 1):

If the sequence is a sequence of reference types, the reference is returned. Otherwise, the value is returned.

But, anyway, this line:

```
obj  = newObjectOfCollectionType
```

does nothing with the sequence content, regardless of sequence's item type.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the source code of Linq method is used `foreach` iterator which returns the element of `IEnumerable` collection.

```
foreach (TSource element in source) {
  if (predicate(element)) return element;
}
```

The C# language specification states (8.8.4)

> "The iteration variable corresponds to a read-only local variable with
>   a scope that extends over the embedded statement."

That is we get a readonly element. For ref types the modifier readonly allows change condition of an object but disallows changing the reference for an object.